# Changing color of status bar after list view is filled in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a little problem that I've been facing for about a week now.

I have a ListView in qt and this list is filled from c++ class. The code right now looks something like this:

```
stackView.push("pageWithList.qml")
stackView.currentPage.init(att) 
//att is the information about from which page the page with list was pushed
```

Then in the pageWithView I have

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    device.setStatusBarColor(desiredColor);
}
```

and in init function it looks like this:

```
function init(pScreenType) {
    screenType = pScreenType;
    switch (screenType) {
    /* 
     *case for each type of screen from which I can get to this page
     */
    case type:
        list.model = app.page.getModel();
        break;
    }
}
```

In the getModel c++ method about 1000 items are returned. Now the problem is tha it takes about a second to load all the items and output for the user looks like this:

1. They click button moving them to the page with list
2. The status bar color changes
3. After one second of loading of the list view the page changes to desired page

Now I want the steps 2 and 3 to be swapped so the color of the status bar changes after the page changes -> after the list model is loaded.

I have tried everything that was in my power, searched whole google, qt documentation and didnt find a soultion to this. If anyone has any advice or a solution or just an inspiration of solving this problem I would be grateful.

Comment: You should provide more code, now it's not clear what you do. What is `pageWithList.qml`, how do you fill the list? Actually `Component.onCompleted` fires when a component was created, not when the list has filled. I would emit some signal from C++ code after you finish filling the list.

Comment: pageWithList is the page that holds the list view. I was thinking about something like that but I have 6 different classes which fill the view... each fills it differently so I wanted an universal solution... but I will try this and we'll see...